# Why there are so many nYields for this simple MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a test db with following indexes:

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "blogger.users"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "name" : 1,
                    "age" : 1
            },
            "name" : "name_1_age_1",
            "ns" : "blogger.users"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "age" : 1,
                    "name" : 1
            },
            "name" : "age_1_name_1",
            "ns" : "blogger.users"
    }
]
```

When running the following query:

```
> db.users.find({"age":{"$gte":21,"$lte":30}})
     .sort({"name":1})
     .hint({"name":1,"age":1})
     .explain()
```

I get the following results

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 83116,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1000000,
    "nscanned" : 1000000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1000000,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1000000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 7812,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1926,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "name" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "age" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "Johny-PC:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

I ran this query multiple times and nYields are always above 7k. There arent any other processes updating, inserting or deleting data. When I run the same query without hint the result is the same.

If I run same query using the other index as hint then nYields are 1200+.

Without hint and sort it is fast but with nYields:500+ and uses another index, as expected.

So is there a way to find out why these many nYields are there and can someone explain why is it so?

**EDIT:**
  A simple find query also has that many nYields. So, the problem is not with index. I might be missing something.

Comment: Ok I am a bit confused here, I am fairly certain that in this case `nscannedObjects` should be 83116 not `1000000` which is oviosuly what is causing the nyields. This is about aoiding a scanandorder in memory by having an index that is pre-sorted for a range. A pefectly valid optimisation.

Comment: At first glance I thought it was a typo. But, as I have used hint to use the second index "name_1_age_1", it makes sense. I might be wrong. I am still learning. I tried it again and gives the same result.

Comment: It does confuse me because nscannedobjects is docments that were scanned, since your query is satisfied by age and name in the index it should only load 83116, however, I can reproduce this and the only way I can stop it from doing that is to switch the order of the index so scanandorder is true, which is just as bad

Comment: As query is using "name_1_age_1" it would first select names, which is the entire document, and use filter to select age data. In the second case, when using "age_1_name_1", it selects age and use in memory sort on name. Which explains the details including scanAndOrder and nscannedObjects.

Comment: My understanding, of which I am seeking clarification on the mongodb user group right now of, is that nscannedobject is physical documents, I.e. your `n` figure

Comment: I just saw your question in google groups. I do think my previous comment does explain that. As I could be wrong, I am also curious and we will wait for experts. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forcing the query to use the wrong index with the `hint` call, as the query needs to first filter by `age` and then sort by `name`.  The index you're telling MongoDB to use can't be efficiently used for that.

Either remove the `hint` call or change it to:

```js
db.users.find({"age":{"$gte":21,"$lte":30}})
 .sort({"name":1})
 .hint("age_1_name_1")
 .explain()
```

The more docs the query needs to scan (`nscannedObjects`) the more times it will yield the read lock as it's waiting for the I/O to complete to fetch the docs. So the less efficient the query, the higher nYields will be. There's nothing wrong with 500+ yields, it just means it's a query that returns a lot of docs (83k in this case).

Comment: @JohnyHK, when I use covered indexing excluding non indexed fields, the indexOnly field is false. Why? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @johny Yeah, ask that as a separate question. Thanks.